# Checkbox and Icons of MFC application are not displayed on Win11 machine

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-10, resources, windows-11

I see a weird issue with my **MFC application** where **check boxes and icons** are disappeared when running it in **Windows 11**.

But the same is working well when running in windows 10.

Does any one have idea on this?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a new MFC application made from scratch?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce with my test application which is made from scratch.